# Convert string to array of json objects, rails 3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, string

I have this string

```
astring='[{"name": "daus", "total": "45", "ios": "30", "android": "15"},{"name": "davus", "total": "38", "ios: 27", "android": "11"}]'
```

and I want to convert it to JSON via

```
ajson = JSON.parse(astring)
```

but I receive this error:

```
JSON::ParserError: 399: unexpected token at '{"name": "davus", "total": "38", "ios: 27", "android": "11"}]'
```

I'm assuming my error is in the way I'm setting up the initial string but haven't been able to solve it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error:

```
"ios: 27" -> "ios": "27"
```